# Access - Check if a value exists in another table after insert

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table with the field "Name" among the others. When I insert a new value in that field, I need a check to see if it exists in another table (same field, "Name"), and if it doesn't, I need that it creates a new row in this table with the value inserted

Example:

```
First Table                        Second Table

Name     Cost                      Name     Cost
John     1000€                     John     1200€
John      200€                     James    2000€
James    2000€
```

If I try to insert, for example, "Mark" in the first table, since it isn't in the second table, it adds a new row in the second, so the result is

```
Second Table

Name     Cost
John     1200€
James    2000€
Mark     0€
```

The check is on the field "name"

[Here](http://wikisend.com/download/444592/Database2.accdb) is the actual database, but it is in italian. The Form "Commesse" has the button "aggiungi cliente" where I write a new name and then save it with "Salva cliente". I need that the other three tables and relative forms to have updated the "Nome_Cliente" field.

Comment: Unless you are trying to add this record through a Form, it might be quiet impossible to achieve this.

Comment: Give us the schema, please. This may be possible using a `DCount` and a query, given that you know what parameter to look for in your query.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Yes, I insert the new value into a Form

Comment: @OverMind Updated first post

Comment: How will your second table know what name to look for? And is it only Name you are concerned with? What if there are 2 Marks but they are different people? Mark is an excellent choice of a name btw ;)

Comment: Totally random name :P BTW it's simpler than that. I'll insert a name in the first table, and if it it isn't present in the second, i need a way to insert it automatically. Yes, I'm concerned only with "Name". In very truth, I've managed of achieve that in some way with Data Macros but it doesn't work very well :(

Comment: ( cc: @PaulFrancis ) Have you considered using an After Insert [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the first table?

Comment: How is the name getting into the table? Is it in a form? Are you clicking a button to save this data? @GordThompson has a good point with using Data Macros, however I stay away from them.

Comment: @OverMind Yes, I insert it through a Form and then save it. I add a link to the actual database in the first so you can understand better

Comment: @GordThompson I'm already using data macros for other similar tasks but with this in particular, I'm having problems

Comment: Sorry - I meant to ask - Are you entering data on the form into textboxes, or is this a datasheet view?

Comment: @OverMind Yes, I enter data on the form

Comment: This will tell you if any records were found in your table: `DCount("[Name]", "YourTableName", "[Name] ='" & Me.YourFieldOnYourForm.Value & "'")` .. There are too many unknowns still (whether or not it's a bound form, what to do when it fails, etc.) for me to supply an answer. But hopefully you can run with this or what Gord suggested.

Comment: @GordThompson, I never actually gave it a thought. As I try to avoid macros as the plague. Sometimes you have to, but I feel a better handle at things could be achieved at Form level.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I almost never use "regular" Macros (the ones that have been in Access all along) but event-driven Data Macros (new since Access 2010) have the advantage of being defined at the table level so they are in effect regardless of how the table is updated, e.g., by *any* form, by SQL statement, by Recordset update, or even by opening the table in Datasheet View.

Comment: @GordThompson, thank you for that explanation. I never knew that the Data Macro are superseded by any other forms. That is very interesting. I am going to have a play around with it now. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do with an After Insert data macro on the first table:

[image: AfterInsert.png]

For more information on data macros, see:

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Comment: I was just thinking, would it be better if we used BeforeInsert over AfterInsert?

Comment: @PaulFrancis After Insert makes more sense in this case because we only want to add the row into the second table if the insert into the first table is successful. Before Change can fire even if the insert is ultimately unsuccessful (e.g., because of a foreign key constraint violation that cancels the insert after the Before Change macro runs).

Comment: Ah ! Makes much more sense. Probably I missed giving a lot more detail to the OP's question. Your explanation makes more sense. Thank you. +1 for that :)